# RenRen social network app issues! Getting PHP errors... Any chinese to help? :)

Tags: php

I'm trying to build an app for the Chinese audience at the social networking site RenRen.

Using their PHP API I'm getting these errors:

> Notice: Undefined index:
>   xn_sig_session_key in
>   C:\renren_test_app\xiaonei.class.php
>   on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined index: xn_sig_user
>   in C:\renren_test_app\header.php on
>   line 61

That's coming from the example PHP app. All I changed in code (at header.php) is the API key/secret.
I'd like to know how to fix this as this looks very fundamental.............. and if someone willing to be more helpful - how do I get; User's name/pic/id.

I do not understand Chinese at all so it makes things a lot harder on me. I'd appriciate if someone posts some code!
I hope someone smarter than me can help here (:

**Edit**:
Got the PHP API from: http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/%25E4%25B8%258B%25E8%25BD%25BD%25E4%25B8%2593%25E5%258C%25BA

Comment: "looks like" you have to configure the session key and user

Comment: Thanks erenon! The session key and user should be passed on to me, from the calling server. Just like Facebook's apps. Otherwise, how would I do anything?

Comment: Can you post your setup page? ie. Canvas Page URL, Canvas callback URL etc

Comment: @SteD: The URL to the app is http://apps.renren.com/moni_poni . Using FireFox you can get the canvas' page url, by inspecting the iframe - I don't want to expose my IP here, hope it's fine by you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iframe shows that xn_sig_added=0, which means that 授权 (authorization) is not yet approved.

> xn_sig_added = 1 表示已授权，此时应用就可以获取到
>   xn_sig_session_key 和 xn_sig_user 了。

Translate to:

> xn_sig_added = 1, which means it's
>   authorized, at this point you could
>   retrieve xn_sig_session_key and
>   xn_sig_user.

Source: [Wiki renren](http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E6%9D%83%E9%99%90)

The 3 ways you can ask for authorization is in the [wiki](http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E6%9D%83%E9%99%90), have a look (use google translate or something).

Hope it helps.

P/S: this is the first time I heard of Renren, it certainly looks like facebook!